# Drop database sql server in appharbor

Tags: sql-server, appharbor, sql-drop

I get a problem with AppHarBor when I use SQL Management Studio to drop database and then I can't create new database in this.
So, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't drop and re-create a database. You should remove the add-on and add it to the app anew. Details on [AppHarbor Support Site](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/10170-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master).